# S3 Class - Converting Data frame into an object

Tags: r, class, dataframe

I was using dataset (data frame with 5 variables and 20000 observations) to make S3 classes. I wanted to make a class called “LongData” that characterizes the structure of this longData dataset. Then I wanted to design classes to represent the concept of a “subject”, a “visit”, and a “room”.

Furthermore, once I have class defined I wanted to  to implement the following functions

first_func: a function that converts a data frame into a “LongData” object
subject: a generic function for extracting subject-specific information
visit: a generic function for extracting visit-specific information
room: a generic function for extracting room-specific information

However, following your student example I am not able to get my class defined. I am kind of stuck how should I proceed with this problem.

However, I am not getting right date to begin with. Then how to go through data for following function as mentioned above.

```
LongData <- function(id, visit, room) {
  out <- list(id= id, visit = visit, room = room
 ,data=data.frame(id = id, visit = visit, room = room))
  class(out) <- "LongData"
  invisible(out)
}

## I want to  make a generic function for extracting customer-specific information
cumstomer <- function(qlist, value) {
    for(i in qlist) {   
        if (value %in% i) { 
            return(i)
        } else {
            return("none")
        }
    }
}

## generic print function 
print.LongData <- function(object) {
    cat("\nID =", object$id,
    "\nVisit =", object$visit, 
    "\nRoom =", object$room,  "\n") 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but `for (i in qlist) {...}` is only ever going to evaluate the first `i` because the `return` statements will exit the function.

Comment: well  i want to extract the specific value of customer id 

e.g. if its not there it 
 >customer(x, 10)
 none 
#if its in there 
 > customer(x, 12)
12

Comment: This is a Coursera homework assignment. Are there StackOverflow customs for answering these questions?